# A way to scale resque workers in and out on dev machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am running Redis/Resque locally on my development machine. During a long-running task, I would like to be able to scale down my worker count to free up some bandwidth without having to cancel the command below and restart with a lower COUNT.

```
 rake environment resque:workers  QUEUE='*' COUNT=10
```

Is it possible to increase/decrease workers dynamically while a queue is processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following plugins:

- https://github.com/kmullin/resque-sliders - Gives you control via the web UI
- https://github.com/frausto/resque-director - Allows you to define "rules" for scaling up and down.